# How do i make that it will show me the file size with only two digits after the dot(point)?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
public static string FormatSize(double size)
        {
            const long BytesInKilobytes = 1024;
            const long BytesInMegabytes = BytesInKilobytes * 1024;
            const long BytesInGigabytes = BytesInMegabytes * 1024;
            const long BytesInTerabytes = BytesInGigabytes * 1024;

            Tuple<double, string> unit;
            if (size < BytesInTerabytes)
                if (size < BytesInGigabytes)
                    if (size < BytesInMegabytes)
                        if (size < BytesInKilobytes)
                            unit = Tuple.Create(size, "B");
                        else
                            unit = Tuple.Create(size / BytesInKilobytes, "KB");
                    else
                        unit = Tuple.Create(size / BytesInMegabytes, "MB");
                else
                    unit = Tuple.Create(size / BytesInGigabytes, "GB");
            else
                unit = Tuple.Create(size, "TB");

            return String.Format("{0} {1}",unit.Item1,  unit.Item2);
        }
```

In this case i see KB and what i get is: 116.1234567890 KB Im getting ten numbers after the point.
How can i make that it will give only two digits after the point ?

Comment: You just need to use formatstring, check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use any of the standard .NET formatting literals. To get a numeric value with two digits after the decimal point, you could use `{0:n2}`:

```
 return String.Format("{0:n2} {1}", unit.Item1, unit.Item2);
```

This should give you:

```
116.12 KB
```

For more info, see the MSDN documentation on [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Use [Math.Round](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round.aspx)

```
return String.Format("{0} {1}",Math.Round(unit.Item1, 2),  unit.Item2);
```